# How to filter JSON object By datetime values?

Tags: python, json, datetime, filter

```
myData = [{'id': 40255674078, 'amount': 100.0, 'date': '21-08-21 - 18:44:17', 'type': 'yatirim'},
          {'amount': 100.0, 'id': 40363908488, 'date': '23-08-21 - 00:34:59', 'type': 'cekim'},
          {'id': 40363733957, 'amount': 100.0, 'date': '23-08-21 - 00:35:26', 'type': 'yatirim'},
          {'id': 40363764873, 'amount': 50.0, 'date': '23-08-21 - 00:35:49', 'type': 'yatirim'},
          {'id': 40363786563, 'amount': 20.0, 'date': '23-08-21 - 00:36:06', 'type': 'yatirim'},
          {'amount': 100.0, 'id': 40372743199, 'date': '23-08-21 - 03:02:35', 'type': 'cekim'},
          {'id': 40378210996, 'amount': 30.0, 'date': '23-08-21 - 06:10:19', 'type': 'yatirim'},
          {'id': 40378346583, 'amount': 20.0, 'date': '23-08-21 - 06:15:59', 'type': 'yatirim'}]
```

There is a data in this section. I want to group the transactions within 24 hours from the `'cekim'` time and the `'cekim'` time + 24 if the `"type" == "cekim"` in this data. As it turns out, there may be 2 or more of these types, how can I group them in smaller form for his `'cekim'` time and 24 hours later?

Comment: Your description of how you want to group the transactions is unclear. It would help if you at least showed what the result would look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access using values
or specifically the date value

```
from datetime import date
the_date = date.fromisoformat('2019-12-04')
json_object = json. loads(myData)
pairs = json_object. items()
for key, value in pairs:
    if date = the_date:
        print(value)
```

this code is a prototype

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution this way.

```
startDateObj = datetime.strptime(myData[0]["date"],%d-%m-%y - %H:%M:%S)
endDateObj = datetime.strptime(myData[0]["date"],%d-%m-%y - %H:%M:%S) + timedelta(days=1)
dateRange = [x for x in myData if datetime.strptime(x["date"],"%d-%m-%y - %H:%M:%S") >= startDateObj and datetime.strptime(x["date"],"%d-%m-%y - %H:%M:%S") <= endDateObj ]
```